# Using Okhttp AWS Signer for s3 upload (PUT)

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-s3

Can I use this signer https://github.com/babbel/okhttp-aws-signer for upload file to s3?
I use this https://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2019-01-03-okhttp-aws-signer.html reference when build my sample app:

```
class AwsSigingInterceptor(private val signer: OkHttpAwsV4Signer) : Interceptor {
    private val dateFormat: ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>

    init {
        dateFormat = object : ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
            override fun initialValue(): SimpleDateFormat {
                val localFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'", Locale.US)
                localFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
                return localFormat
            }
        }
    }

    override fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response =
        chain.run {
            val request = request()

            val newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("x-amz-date", dateFormat.get().format(clock.now()))
                .addHeader("host", request.url().host())
                .build()

            val signed = signer.sign(newRequest, "<accessKeyId>", "<secretAccessKey>")

            proceed(signed)
        }
}
```

but I didn't see any `x-amz-content-sha256` there.. only additional `Authorization` header added. When I try the debug result header in Advanced Rest Client or Postman, it says "Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256"

Comment: After reading part of its source code, it looks like the author forgot to add that header in before generating the signature. Based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html), could you try to add a `x-amz-content-sha256` header with the value `SHA256Hash(the file or payload you want to upload)`?

Comment: In Postman, `x-amz-content-sha256` header is sha256 hash of empty string which is `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855` (cmiiw) and I just need to insert image in the body using binary mode. So, in my code I just supply requestbody and the rest build in AwsSigingInterceptor including x-amz-content-sha256. But it still says 403 Forbidden: signature calculate doesn' match

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. By any chance did you get it done?. If so, please post the answer.

Comment: @MadhuJayarama I'm using other way to build my code. I can't waste my time to solve that issue.